# Sigma-algebra on $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ generated by $\epsilon = \{\{1,2,4,5\},\{2,3\}\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
Let $\epsilon = \{\{1,2,4,5\},\{2,3\}\}$. Find $\sigma$ ($\epsilon$), generated by ($\epsilon$), and justify answer.

Could someone please give me some direction and help with this question please.

If I say $\{1,2,4,5\}=A$ and $\{2,3\}=B$ then $A^c=\{3\}$ and $B^c=\{1,4,5\}$. But since $A\cup B^c=A$ and $A^c\cup B=B$, do we just get that the: $\sigma(\epsilon)=\{\Omega,\emptyset,A,B,A^c,B^c,A^c \cup B^c\}$?

So $\sigma(\epsilon)=\{\emptyset, \{1,2,3,4,5\}, \{1,2,4,5\}, \{2,3\}, \{3\}, \{1,4,5\}, \{1,3,4,5\}\}$?

Comment: You left out $A \cap B$.

Comment: Thank you! So σ(ϵ)={∅,{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,4,5},{2,3},{3},{1,4,5},{1,3,4,5},{2}} is correct?

Comment: The answer in your last comment (with 8 elements) is correct. One way of looking at it: you saw that you can get the singleton sets $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$, and that means that you can always include or exclude those two numbers from any set you want. On the other hand, the three elements $1,4,5$ are inextricably linked to one another: there's no way to include some of them without including all of them (and same for excluding). So a set in the $\sigma$-algebra gets only three "choices": include $2$ or not, include $3$ or not, and include $1,4,5$ or not.